# Code Analysis from Common Intermediate Language (CIL)

Tags: .net, optimization, profiler, cil, cci

I would like to do some fairly basic program analysis on my .NET code (which is a combination of .dlls, .exe and C# code). Using Microsoft's [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/), I first converted the code to it's IL form using which I would like to construct a call graph. Once I have the call graph, are there some standard tools that can be leveraged in order to gain insights in code complexity, identifying bottlenecks, memory footprint etc.? Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: The best way to find performance bottlenecks is with a profiler. Memory profilers will help you with memory issues. It's very hard to analyse that kind of thing without running the code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am not looking for memory leaks/issues per se. Rather, trying to gauge some idea of a process' memory footprint, i.e., how many object allocations etc. (all within the domain of static program analysis)

Comment: I don't know who dinged you, but I don't think it was justified.  Adding an anti-ding.    I have no ideas what tools are available on top of CCI (CIL isn't Microsoft as far as I know so I'm a little confused about which infrastructure you are actually talking about).   In any case, I'd guess there isn't a lot out there, but that's a guess.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but JetBrains do quite some static analysis in their products (resharper for example) and are doing something with a project called N2 which seems to have some affinity to what you are looking for. See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/06/jetbrains-and-nemerle/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is pretty much impossible. The count of object allocations could vary wildly depending on specific input.

For example, imagine there was a method in your program that allocated a lot of objects, but it would run only under some condition. If your analysis was to asses the count of object allocations accurately, it would need to know whether the method ran. And the only way to do that is to actually evaluate that condition, which means you would actually need to run the program.

And memory footprint is probably even more difficult: it would require you to track the complete object graph and simulate the GC.

In short: the best way to find out performance characteristics of your program is to actually run it. Doing the same using static analysis would be hard and inaccurate. Don't forget that [it's impossible to find out whether program completes using static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). I think what you want is even more difficult.

Comment: I think  you go too far in underrating static analysis.   Running the program may not exhibit any problems for a any run you have tried, yet your application could still be buggy/leaky.  That's the point of static analysis.   I'll agree that dynamic profiling is widely accepted, easily done and often pretty useful.

Comment: But the OP doesn't seem to be looking for bugs or leaks. He seems to want to get statistics. And I really do think that static analysis is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: He says  "gain insights", that usually means "by any means possible" but he is pretty adamant about wanting static analysis.

Comment: He explicitly says that's not what he wants in [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462483/code-analysis-from-common-intermediate-language-cil/11466548#comment15132028_11462483): “I am not looking for memory leaks/issues per se.”

Comment: Ira, svick- Thanks for your inputs! I have absolutely nothing against dynamic profiling. My question here intended to just ask as to how far can static analysis (tools) go. While conditional object allocations are difficult to predict without symbolic/concolic testing, the worse case should theoretically be possible to know (by tracking the Newobj IL statements). One way to do this was making an IL parser, writing scripts to generate call graphs and tracking these variables. However, before getting my hands dirty, I wanted to know if there are any tools available.